# Laravel Lighthouse Where to place non root field resolvers?

Tags: laravel-lighthouse, graphql-php

In the example in the documentation of lighthouse they give a example method for resolving non-root fields.

```
<?php

use App\Models\User;

function resolveUserId(User $user): string
{
    return $user->name; // test...
}
```

So my guess is that lighthouse will search for a resolveUser{Field} method, and call it if it exists. But where do I place the method? there's no class name or namespace in the example.

type Query @guard(with: ["api"]) {
me: User! @auth
}

```
type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    email: String!
    posts (content_contains: [String]): [Post!]! @hasMany #Would like to be able to resolve content_contains somehow...
    created_at: DateTime!
    updated_at: DateTime!
}
```

Documentation URL:

https://lighthouse-php.com/4.9/the-basics/fields.html#resolving-non-root-fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you wanting to use `@field`, for example? It can be just any class, with any namespace. Just be sure to explicit it. For example, in `app/Graphql/UserPostsResolver.php` you can have a class with a `handle` function. So in your schema you would use `posts: [Post!] @field(resolver: "App\\Graphql\\UserPostsResolver@handle")`

Comment: Oh I thought that it would search for the method somewhere automatically like queries are found by having same (capitalized) name in app\GraphQL\Queries\???.php